# Does the order of points matter in spline interpolation in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

I am using MatLab to pick the data point with my mouse and then fit it with a spline. I found the following function could do the job

```
[xy, spcv] = getcurve()
```

it returns the x & y of the points I picked with a mouse

```
x = [ -0.8103   -0.6740   -0.5599   -0.5120   -0.4936   -0.4530   -0.4494   -0.4494   -0.4494   -0.4751 -0.5157   -0.6409   -0.6667   -0.7772   -0.7772   -0.6998   -0.5304   -0.4641   -0.2431    0.0110 0.1142    0.1989    0.2836    0.3499    0.3499    0.4125    0.5267]
y = [0.8621    0.8388    0.7640    0.7547    0.7266    0.6472    0.5911    0.5257    0.4696    0.3668 0.2967    0.2360    0.2220    0.0724   -0.1472   -0.1939   -0.2874   -0.4743   -0.5304   -0.5257 -0.4930   -0.3668   -0.2967   -0.2593   -0.2593   -0.2827   -0.3715
```

plotting the spline spcv returned by getcurve(), I get the following figure

[image]

By reading the code of getcurve, I see that it uses cscvn to return *a parametric `natural' cubic spline that interpolates to the given points*. It may be the reason why the curve is passing all given points instead of the best-fit curve. I would like to replace it with a cubic smoothing spline as below

```
sp = spaps(x, y, 0.);
xx = -1:0.01:2;
plot(xx, fnval(sp, xx), 'b', 'linewidth', 2); hold on;
plot(x, y, 'ko');
```

which gives me something strange as follow
[image]

It looks like it is trying to fit the data points from small x to big x instead of the order given by the data sequence. I am expecting a smooth curve in red as below (I draw it by hand)

[image]

I am looking for a solution that I can replace cscvn with spaps in getcurve and keep the correct order. Thanks.

Comment: Your smoothing spline fits a function y(x). You cannot have two y values for the same x. This is why it treats the data that way. You need a different function to fit a curve through 2D space. I don’t know what function that is off the top of my head, but it must exist somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I do more research. It seems that x must be strictly increasing to use smooth spline interpolation. I don't know what function could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.-** To interpolate curves that fold back you have to **parametrize** `x` and `y`

```
x = [ -0.8103   -0.6740   -0.5599   -0.5120   -0.4936   -0.4530   -0.4494   -0.4494   -0.4494   -0.4751 -0.5157   -0.6409   -0.6667   -0.7772   -0.7772   -0.6998   -0.5304   -0.4641   -0.2431    0.0110 0.1142    0.1989    0.2836    0.3499    0.3499    0.4125    0.5267];
y = [0.8621    0.8388    0.7640    0.7547    0.7266    0.6472    0.5911    0.5257    0.4696    0.3668 0.2967    0.2360    0.2220    0.0724   -0.1472   -0.1939   -0.2874   -0.4743   -0.5304   -0.5257 -0.4930   -0.3668   -0.2967   -0.2593   -0.2593   -0.2827   -0.3715];

figure(1)
ax1=gca
fnplt(cscvn([x;y])); hold(ax1,'on');
plot(ax1,x,y,'o');
grid on

sp = spaps(x, y, 0.);
xx = -1:0.01:2;
figure(2)
plot(xx, fnval(sp, xx), 'b', 'linewidth', 2); hold on;
plot(x, y, 'ko'); grid on


nx=[1:numel(x)];ny=[1:numel(y)];

fx=fit(nx',x','poly3','Normalize','on','Robust','Bisquare')
fy=fit(ny',y','poly3','Normalize','on','Robust','Bisquare')
plot(ax1,fx(nx),fy(ny))

f2x=fit(nx',x','cubicinterp','Normalize','on')
f2y=fit(ny',y','cubicinterp','Normalize','on')
plot(ax1,f2x(nx),f2y(ny))

f3x=fit(nx',x','smoothingspline','Normalize','on')
f3y=fit(ny',y','smoothingspline','Normalize','on')
plot(ax1,f3x(nx),f3y(ny))

f4x=fit(nx',x','poly1','Normalize','on')
f4y=fit(ny',y','poly1','Normalize','on')
plot(ax1,f4x(nx),f4y(ny))

f5x=fit(nx',x','poly11','Normalize','on')
f5y=fit(ny',y','poly11','Normalize','on')
plot(ax1,f5x(nx),f5y(ny))

f6x=fit(nx',x','rat33','Normalize','on')
f6y=fit(ny',y','rat33','Normalize','on')
plot(ax1,f6x(nx),f6y(ny))
```

[image]

**2.-** Note that `nx` and `ny` have same amount of samples as `x` and `y`.

If you interpolate `x` over `nx` and `y` over `ny` and then apply fit the resulting curve will get closer to all points in the way you asked for.

Comment: Thanks John, it makes sense to use two parametrize splines instead. I am playing around withe the code you just post, so what happens if I would like to best fit the given points instead of finding a curve passing through all the points? Anything I can do with something like parametrize smoothing spline?